# RSS aggregator; how to insert only new items

Tags: php, rss

A [tutorial here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/php-functions/xml/building-a-php-rss-aggregator.html) shows how to build an agregator in PHP but I'm having some trouble finding the best way not to insert the same items in my database.

If I were to run the script on http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/feed/ and then run it again in 5 minutes it'll just insert the same items again.

That tutorial just has an interval time specified in wich it will reload the RSS feed and save all the items.

I was wondering if RSS implement some request header that will only send the items after a certain date. I see [here](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) that I could use lastBuildDate and mabe ignore channels that have a date older than last fetched but it doesn't say if that is mandatory.

My question here is: how can I check RSS feeds regularly and insert it in a database without inserting the same item more than once?

I'm thinking the only way to do it is to check if a record already exist using link and only insert if it doesn't exist already. I know link is optional but I won't save items that don't have one anyway. This seems a bit inefficient though; checking before every insert might be fine in the beginning but when the database starts filling up it might get very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to use a few different strategies depending on how well the site you are consuming has implemented the spec.

First I would try adding a unique index on the database for the GUID value, GUIDs by there nature should be unique, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier - then depending on which DB you are using you should be able to use syntax like `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` and just have the update syntax not really do anything

If some sites don't have a guid field (I am assuming you will end up consuming more than just the example) you could add the unique on the siteId field and the either the time or the title, both are less than ideal of course contacting the site own to get them to implement a guid might work too ;)

You could also run an md5 hash on the post content and store that alongside the post, that should stop duplicates too.

How big are you expecting the DB to get? with proper indexing I would have thought that it would have to be huge before it runs slow; indexes on siteId, guid, time and/or hash and limited to just 1 row and just the rowId should be quick enough, epscialyl if you can get your script to run commandline / on a cron job rather than through a webserver

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was thinking of setting unique constraint on the link value (if there is no article to link to I'm not going to save it). Atom seems to have multiple link elements with edit,self and alternate properties so I'll have to check how to save those. There will be about 250 feeds to read so I'll assume items are chronologically ordered. When a link is in the database it'll stop processing the rest. This might cause some problems but will monitor it closely. Daily everything older than 7 days will be archived. Not sure yet how many items there will be.

Comment: I was kind of hoping RSS had some implementation of only providing items that are not already fetched based on some http request header but could not find it. This is probably because it doesn't exist and if it does then there is no guarantee the sites implement it.

Comment: I haven't heard of such a thing, and iirc RSS stands for Really Simple Syndication, so I can't see it have many advanced features. Plus from a provider's server perspective if everyone who consumed your RSS feed was passing in different parameters it could really hammer it.